# Mobile login with Google no longer working on Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin

I have a Xamarin mobile app I'm maintaining and API hosted on Azure (didn't write the original code, and I'm not particularly familiar with these platforms). Recently the login began working inconsistently on the iOS and Android apps - most prevalent on iOS. This happened with no updates to the server code or mobile code.

Here's the mobile login code:

```
public Authenticator()
        {
            client = new MobileServiceClient(APIHelper.ServerUrl);
        }

        public async Task<AuthResponse> Authenticate(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
        {
            try
            {
                MobileServiceUser user = await client.LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController, provider, "myurischeme", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "access_type", "offline" }, { "prompt", "consent" } });
                if (user != null)
                {
                    Preferences.Set("account_tokenid", user.UserId);
                    return new AuthResponse() { success = true, userId = user.UserId, token = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception: " + e.Message);
            }

            return new AuthResponse() { success = false };
        }
```

My request times out on `MobileServiceUser user = await client.LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController, provider, "myurischeme", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "access_type", "offline" }, { "prompt", "consent" } });`

I'm not seeing any errors on Azure (although again, not super familiar with the error checking in the console). It seems like the app doesn't know the api is up.

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.2.0, which *seems* like it lost support in March 2023?

I need Google login, so I'm thinking about switching to WebAuthenticator? I'm mainly stumped because this all started failing with no updates.

Comment: Did you mean the request worked on the android and ios before but don't work now?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT The request works inconsistently now - usually on Android, but not always, and less than half the time on iOS

Comment: Did you try to post an issue for the package on the github?